# Bootstrap Navbar shows in very weird form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I run Ruby on Rails 5 and i use bootstrap gem. The issue i am having is that 
when i put the html in one of my partials i have very weird looking 'nav-bar'.

```
<html><head>
    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-09a09de7df140e59268bd2c94d4ba54f4e8477100ad6ca7894899b63e99bf8c7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload">
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/tether/tether.self-49a614f96d3d9b228d4f800376a8db0a8315c1f10eb759f66a528112980505de.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/tether.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-4e71bfbf6aff83432bb0f204b1cfa3beaf9d05f0d2acf9ec752924a628245be1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/util.self-ee646345d4a58a58a1c5f97a3def830f24884ebd628cedc00c5cc9bb748f8dcf.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-8ec79d32a4387947ba9c697a802d190e85eaabd2d7868e188ceb32bfaff27090.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-11f2f59490a5ed1ee00730174836d887cf01ddd797cf2b080e7d9dd1f988faa3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-a1068285d9397c8a3fe8911b395c0ca7eaa7d98460f68a32896dbdea5904f8ae.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-d36e6561deb41e4e98a568aa5be6b3d14a6d4d604d6923d3732ed8d97d734854.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-9001a6392843799bd3f8fefa8f2b90bc2ea9e0a70cb5148039787b50b18abc51.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-86f0500b4628eba403a8e8a2c31a642d399d7efebb27ccc40f03b0f98f458461.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-bc2becbc0f4b31f6fabf6aa80923e509fa9a0fb55165dac75333164564d619b2.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-8c546e0109ea36cfbe17faff530986e24eb7043bd1237c64bcb8257f24b0285c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-35e74be099c220a4b49c8a825b32613a19641d8b4538a78e819a8b9a75de2b40.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-23ed39658a0cf53b747d72cc537e52bc9fc33b3d8eab3872d38186e3631b519c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-636159b35205da4142a43bc02d2849d77d3ac07a0946211585cde15a9c6ff21f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/jquery.min.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-1641ec3e8ea24ed63601e86efcca7f9266e09f390e82199d56aa7e4bd50e1aa9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-6e0514260c1aa76eaf252412ce74e63f68819fd19bf740595f592c5ba4c36537.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-4d37d7bcf4b0b32507438063ae47ba88dd0178863f7c7a2c7125b221eefea772.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navigation-clean">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand navbar-link" href="#">Company Name</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navcol-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</body></html>
```

After that i have a very weird nav-bar it looks like on the picture below.
[image: This is nav-bar]

[image: this is nav-bar when clicked]

The most important that this nav-bar is inline it looks like this image below
[image: original nav-bar]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
<div class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">links toggle button</span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white white icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white white icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#"><span class="navbar-brand">Company Name</span></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: right;">
        <li><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">
                Dropdown<span class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just did try yours HTML , unfortunately it is looking not good, still have this issue, please check link [bootstrap issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Q94paOTL1iMk9lcGtkTkk3STg/view)

Comment: Owe, it may be that other CSS are affecting your layout. Could you please  remove the parts where they style an element in the navigation bar? Also, please use the bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js files. I hope it works out better...

Answer (score 1):

---

Your code works fine

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">links toggle button</span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white white icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white white icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="mdl-color--white icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#"><span class="navbar-brand">Company Name</span></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: right;">
        <li><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">First Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Second Item</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Third Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: for sure some other css overriding bootstrap styling in your code